# me sale error,que hago

Tags: aplicación-web

Algoritmo CajeroAutomatico
Definir opcion, saldo, monto, nuevoSaldo Como Real
Definir pin, pinIngresado Como Entero

```
saldo = 1000  // Saldo inicial en el cajero automático

Escribir "Bienvenido al Cajero Automático"
Escribir "Por favor, ingrese su PIN:"
Leer pin

Si pin = 1234 Entonces  // Suponiendo que el PIN es 1234
    Repetir
        Escribir "1. Consultar Saldo"
        Escribir "2. Retirar dinero"
        Escribir "3. Salir"
        Escribir "Por favor, seleccione una opción:"
        Leer opcion
        
        Segun opcion
            Caso 1:
                Escribir "Su saldo actual es: ", saldo
            Caso 2:
                Escribir "Ingrese la cantidad que desea retirar:"
                Leer monto
                Si monto <= saldo Entonces
                    nuevoSaldo = saldo - monto
                    Escribir "Retire su dinero. Su saldo restante es: ", nuevoSaldo
                    saldo = nuevoSaldo
                Sino
                    Escribir "Fondos insuficientes"
                FinSi
            Caso 3:
                Escribir "Gracias por usar el cajero automático. ¡Hasta luego!"
            En Otro Caso:
                Escribir "Opción no válida. Por favor, seleccione una opción válida."
        FinSegun
        
    Hasta Que opcion = 3
Sino
    Escribir "PIN incorrecto. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo."
FinSi
```

FinAlgoritmo

a la hora de ejecutarlo y voy a poner la opcion de cuanto saldo tengo y me sale 0,me sale error 106 no se que hacer

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! arreglemos primero tu pregunta, que es un lio... esto de aplicacion web tiene absolutamente nada.. es pseint? entonces usa esa etiqueta, para la gente que sepa de eso te pueda ayudar. Que es el error 106?? que dice? donde lo tira?

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y arregla todo eso ;)